# Getting single entry in outlook export to excel worksheet vba macro based on name

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Ok, so I made a macro to copy elements from outlook mail bodies if the mail subject is addequate. The only problem is that the macro will keep adding the same person multiple times.
I was wondering if it is possible to make a function that iterates through rows, have it called right before I start filling the excel worksheet and implementing a test after it to check if names already do appear in the iteration. I am really unfamiliar with how functions work in vba and I'd really appreciate an example.

```
Sub ExportToExcel()
    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim xlWB As Object
    Dim xlSheet As Object
    Dim rCount As Long
    Dim enviro As String
    Dim strPath As String
    Dim ns As NameSpace
    Dim item As Object
    Dim inbox As MAPIFolder
    Dim bodyString As String
    Dim auxString As String
    Dim name As String
    Dim date1 As String
    Dim date2 As String
    ' Get Excel set up
enviro = CStr(Environ("USERPROFILE"))
'the path of the workbook
 strPath = enviro & "\Documents\test.xlsx"
     On Error Resume Next
     Set xlApp = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")
     If Err <> 0 Then
         Application.StatusBar = "Please wait while Excel source is opened ... "
         Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
         bXStarted = True
     End If
     On Error GoTo 0
     'Open the workbook to input the data
     Set xlWB = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(strPath)
     Set xlSheet = xlWB.Sheets("Sheet1")
    ' Process the message record

    On Error Resume Next
'Find the next empty line of the worksheet
rCount = xlSheet.Range("B" & xlSheet.Rows.Count).End(-4162).Row
'needed for Exchange 2016. Remove if causing blank lines.
If rCount <> 1 Then
rCount = rCount + 1
End If
    Set item = ActiveExplorer.Selection.item(1)
    Set ns = GetNamespace("MAPI")
    Set inbox = ns.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
    For Each item In inbox.Items
        If TypeOf item Is MailItem Then
            If item.Subject = "Leave Request" Then
                bodyString = item.Body
                name = item.Sender
                name = Replace(name, ",", "")
                name = Replace(name, "-", " ")
                bodyString = Replace(bodyString, vbCrLf, "")
                bodyString = Replace(bodyString, "Hello, ", "")
                bodyString = Replace(bodyString, " has created a leave request from ", "")
                bodyString = Replace(bodyString, " to ", "")
                bodyString = Replace(bodyString, ". Please find the created Leave Request in attachment Best regards,", "")
                bodyString = Replace(bodyString, " ", "")
                bodyString = Replace(bodyString, " ", "")
                auxString = Right(bodyString, 20)
                date1 = Left(auxString, 10)
                date2 = Right(auxString, 10)
                    xlSheet.Range("A" & rCount) = name
                    xlSheet.Range("B" & rCount) = date1
                    xlSheet.Range("C" & rCount) = date2
                    xlWB.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:C").EntireColumn.AutoFit
                    rCount = rCount + 1

            End If
        End If
    Next item
     xlWB.Close 1
     If bXStarted Then
         xlApp.Quit
     End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Well, you could have something check all the names right after `If item.Subject = "Leave Request" Then`, however, couldn't someone be submitting a leave request for a second time? In that case, you probably need to have it check against the names, and then maybe the date received?

Comment: i thought about that, but the request specified only that there are no other names; i suppose i need to edit the code to add more dates in other rows in that case, but i suppose it's a similar process, only add a test for dates after the test for the name

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you capture the name of the sender, add it to a dictionary object (you will find a lot of examples on the internet on how to create and use a dictionary object in VBA). Then add an `IF` condition just before you start formatting your `bodyString` (i.e. `If oD.Exists(name) Then`). If the name already exists in the dictionary, skip the rest. If the name doesn't exist, add it to dictionary and then carry on with formatting `bodyString` and adding it to your sheet

Comment: Why before formatting the bodyString? Shouldn't I implement a test after I am done formatting the name, or will the Exists function check for a match in the entire body of the string?

Comment: Logically I would first get the `name`. Check if the name already exists. If it does then you don't need to do anything else. Essentially I think we are both saying the same thing, I just hadn't seen that you were capturing `bodyString` before `name`